# PopupMenu click causing RecyclerView to scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, popupmenu

I have an overflow button inside a `CardView` in `Recyclerview`. Whenever I am clicking the button,I show a popup menu but also `RecyclerView` is scrolling down one item. Can anyone please help me stop this unwanted scrolling?

Basically I am trying to replicate the same overflow button behavior as in Playstore.

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_tracks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivTracks"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/unknown"
           />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgbtn_overflow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_overflow"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /> 
 </RelativeLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final TracksViewHolder tracksViewHolder, int i) {

    tracksViewHolder.imgBtnOverflow.setTag(i);
    tracksViewHolder.imgBtnOverflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
            final int position = (Integer) v.getTag();

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext,tracksViewHolder.imgBtnOverflow);

            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater()
                    .inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_overflow, popup.getMenu());


            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                 if(mPopUpClick!=null)
                     mPopUpClick.actionOnPopUpItemClick(position,item,songs.get(position));
                    return true;
                }
            });

            popup.show(); //showing popup menu
        }
    });

}
```

**UPDATE:**
Got the issue .When the popup menu displays,it slides the list down so as to display the whole dropdown. How to adjust popup to display up/down depending on the space available?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Tried using android.widget.PopupMenu instead of android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu and Voila, it works. So is it a bug in Support library. Can great developers out here confirm the same?

Comment: Same for me, using android.widget.PopupMenu works so far.

Comment: Thank you, so very much! I spent an hour struggling with this!
For anyone who arrives after me: This is true even in 2019. 
Use: android.widget.PopupMenu
Not: androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu

Answer (score 10):

You can have your AnchorView override `requestRectangleOnScreen()` and return false. This will prevent any parent `ScrollView` from scrolling.

So, in your case, `imgBtnOverflow` would be a custom `ImageButton`, like so:

```
/**
 * A custom {@link ImageButton} which prevents parent ScrollView scrolling when used as the
 * anchor for a {@link android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu}
 */
public class NonScrollImageButton extends ImageButton {

    public NonScrollImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requestRectangleOnScreen(Rect rectangle, boolean immediate) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Props to jankovd (https://gist.github.com/jankovd/19ef35efd1f00e9213fa)

An issue has been filed against the Support PopupMenu here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=135439

Comment: Link to issuetracker is dead

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, and I use this way:

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {
            @Override
            public boolean requestChildRectangleOnScreen(RecyclerView parent, View child, Rect rect, boolean immediate) {
                return false;
            }
        };
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

RecyclerView user layoutmanager to manage layout, so I think change layoutmanger behaver is the bettor solution.

Answer (score 0):

`requestRectangleOnScreen`not work for me, in my case, `requestRectangleOnScreen`not called, when show popupMenu.
my solution is override `requestChildRectangleOnScreen`, and reture false, work well.

```
public class PopupAncorRecyclerViewPager extends RecyclerView {
        @Override
    public boolean requestChildRectangleOnScreen(View child, Rect rect, boolean immediate) {
        return false;
    }
}
```