# Avoid that a popup menu scrolls a view

Tags: android, popup, popupmenu

I'm using a `RecyclerView` and whenever I click an item that's quite near to the bottom, the popup scrolls the `RecyclerView` so that it can show the popup underneath it. If I scroll to the bottom, the `PopupMenu` can't scroll the `RecyclerView` anymore and shows on top of the item.

I want that the `PopupMenu` shows on top always, if it does not fit underneath...

Can I somehow achieve that?

Comment: It happens the same to me... Looks like that if you don't use the support library one: ```android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu``` it works but then I can't style it using ```parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu"```.

Comment: The Android Support Library bug tracker for this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=135439

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid scrolling on button click inside recyclerview item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473977/avoid-scrolling-on-button-click-inside-recyclerview-item)

Comment: If someone out there has the same problem, this will save your day! https://stackoverflow.com/a/29493055/7953908